# How to use truth table to check argument validity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> Determine whether the following argument is valid:
>
> $P\to R$     (premise 1)
>
> $Q\to R$     (premise 2)
>
> ~(P v Q) (premise 3)
>
> Therefore, $R$  (conclusion)

I made a truth table: when premise 1, 2, 3 are all true, $R$ can be both T and F. How to use my truth table to check the argument's validity?

Comment: What does it mean for an argument to be valid?

Comment: Re the title: the conclusion must be T in every row of the t-t where all premises are T.